# Number schedule by its size

Tags: java

I want to write a program which will scan 3 inputs(numbers) in cmd and it will give a sorting by size.

For example I insert 10 3 8
program should print 3 8 10

I tried with this program but cmd give me errors

Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class bySize{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();

        if((a<b)&&(b<c)){
            System.out.println(a,b,c);
        } 
        else if((a<c)&&(c<b)){
            System.out.println(a,c,b);
        }
        else if((b<a)&&(a<c)){
            System.out.println(b,a,c);
        }
        else if((b<c)&&(c<a)){
            System.out.println(b,c,a);
        }
        else if((c<b)&&(b<a)){
            System.out.println(c,b,a);
        }
        else if((c<a)&&(a<b)){
            System.out.println(c,a,b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "cmd give me errors" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the error(s) that you're getting, along with the specific details of how you're running the program.

Comment: use System.out.println(a+", "+b+", "+c); this style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class BySize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();

        if ((a < b) && (b < c)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",a, b, c);
        } else if ((a < c) && (c < b)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",a, c, b);        
        } else if ((b < a) && (a < c)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",b, a, c);
        } else if ((b < c) && (c < a)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",b, c, a);
        } else if ((c < b) && (b < a)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",c, b, a);
        } else if ((c < a) && (a < b)) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d",c, a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with your `System.out.println()` statement which can take only one argument or no argument while you are passing three arguments to it. If you still want to use `System.out.println()`, you can use it like `System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c)` i.e. by combining all your three arguments as a single argument.